# WCF - General Question

Tags: wcf

I'm writing a WCF services that will be exposed to number of customers. Some customers use .NET client and other use Java and php etc.

When developing the WCF Services do I need to worry about whether consumers will be .NET or others? In other words, if I return .NET collections i.e List will the Java client deserializes this easily or should I only return primitive types e.g. Array.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually not, no. I have several web services written in WCF + SOAP and have Java Clients using Axis2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do the "normal" WCF development workflow - no.

WCF is designed from the group up to be as interoperable as possible; anything you can express in the WSDL/XSD that describes your service should be useable by other systems, e.g. Java or others.

You cannot however use .NET specific "trickery" to get around some of WCF's limitations (e.g. sharing contract assembly between server and client) - those wouldn't be portable. Also: you cannot use any .NET specific types that aren't serializable in your data contracts.

Comment: Are you sure about this: "Also: you cannot use any .NET specific types (like Exception) in your data contracts"... I don't think that's accurate. As long as the type is marked as serializable (which many ".NET specific types" are), all should be good.

Comment: @Steve: explain to me how Java should deal with a .NET `Exception` type..... it works for your own types, which you can decorate as needed - but it will **not** work for many built-in .NET native types. Trust me - I've run into several of those issues.....

Comment: @marc_s: "explain to me..." - Well, when you request a WSDL from a WCF service, WCF spiders your entire contract including all data types, and generates XML definitions and returns them with the WSDL. You can see these when you use types like "Guid" which WCF converts into an xs:string with a regex-based restriction. For System.Drawing.PointF, this is converted into a simple XML Type, etc. "Built-in" Types and "Custom" types aren't really different from each other. Now, if you're talking about THROWING exceptions, that is a bit different... but it's handled with WCF componentry.

Comment: @Steve: well, I guess the typical expectation would be that the receiving client could then "reconstruct" that `Exception` object and just use it - which of course won't work on Java or PHP. You might be able to inspect some of the properties.... `Exception` is serializable, so that might indeed work (just as data/properties)

Comment: @marc_s: How is "You might be able to inspect some of the properties" different from "reconstructing" the object and "just using it"? Your example, Exception, is serializable and works just as one would expect (http://bit.ly/mJAvq4) so are many/most other "built-in" types.

Comment: @marc_s: I see you've edited the post... I agree with it the way it stands now.

Comment: Thanks @Marc & Steve, appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

No lists will not be an issue for java etc. Try to use the basicHttpBinding binding for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Thanks @Ali, appreciate your answer. It's ver useful. Thank you.